# Basic Python Parsing XML with xml.etree - Issue

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, minidom

I am trying to parse XML and am hard time having. I dont understand why the results keep printing `[<Element 'Results' at 0x105fc6110>]`
I am trying to extract `Social` from my example with the

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse("test.xml")
results = root.findall("Results")
print results #[<Element 'Results' at 0x105fc6110>]
              # WHAT IS THIS??


for result in results:
    print result.find("Social") #None
```

the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<List1>
    <NextOffset>AAA</NextOffset>
    <Results>
        <R>
            <D>internet.com</D>
            <META>
                <Social>
                    <v>http://twitter.com/internet</v>
                    <v>http://facebook.com/internet</v>
                </Social>
                <Telephones>
                    <v>+1-555-555-6767</v>
                </Telephones>
            </META>
        </R>
    </Results>
</List1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findall` returns a `list` of `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` objects. In your case, you only have 1 `Result` node, so you could use `find` to look for the first/unique match.

Once you got it, you have to use `find` using the `.//` syntax which allows to search in anywhere in the tree, not only the one directly under `Result`.

Once you found it, just `findall` on `v` tag and print the text:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse("test.xml")
result = root.find("Results")

social = result.find(".//Social")

for r in social.findall("v"):
    print(r.text)
```

results in:

```
http://twitter.com/internet
http://facebook.com/internet
```

note that I did not perform validity check on the xml file. You should check if the `find` method returns `None` and handle the error accordignly.

Note that even though I'm not confident myself with xml format, I learned all that I know on parsing it by following this [lxml tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html).

Comment: Specifically, your problem was that without a path expression, `findall` and `find` search only the children of the node, not all descendants of the node. `Results` is a child of the root element `List1`, so your first `findall` found it, but `Social` is not a child of `Results` so `find` doesn't find it when searching by name.

Answer (score 2):

`results = root.findall("Results")` is a `list` of `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` objects.

```
type(results)
# list
type(results[0])
# xml.etree.ElementTree.Element
```

`find` and `findall` only look within *first* children. The `iter` method will iterate through matching sub-children at any level.

#### Option 1

If `<Results>` could potentially have more than one `<Social>` element, you could use this:

```
for result in results:
    for soc in result.iter("Social"):
        for link in soc.iter("v"):
            print link.text
```

That's worst case scenario. If you know there'll be one `<Social>` per `<Results>` then it simplifies to:

```
for soc in root.iter("Social"):
    for link in soc.iter("v"):
        print link.text
```

both return

```
"http://twitter.com/internet"
"http://facebook.com/internet"
```

---

#### Option 2

Or use nested list comprehensions and do it with one line of code. Because Python...

```
socialLinks = [[v.text for v in soc] for soc in root.iter("Social")]

# socialLinks == [['http://twitter.com/internet', 'http://facebook.com/internet']]
```

`socialLinks` is list of lists. The outer list is of `<Social>` elements (only one in this example)
Each inner list contains the text from the `v` elements within each particular `<Social>` element .

Comment: good. I had to test it because I wasn't sure that `iter` was going deep enough. It does. Nice.